# FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

Tags: php, fpdf

well I get this error trying to use php class FPDF:

```
FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file (output started at
/mnt/webc/e1/12/5691512/htdocs/adminpanel/fpdf/test.php:1)
```

My test.php

```
<?php
require_once("fpdf.php");
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

There are no blanks or anything... So where is the error???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some editors adds [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the start of a file.

View your file in hex and remove it

Answer (score 0):

it is becouse of two reason

1-there is no leading space before the opening 
2-are some data has been output before

The solution of 2 reson is 
go to fpdf.inc.php

and find this funciton

```
function Output($name='', $dest='') {
```

and then in the defination of this function write this at starting

```
ob_clean();
```

this will clean the previous output.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was the deprecation warnings. I added  & ~E_DEPRECATED to my error_reporting in my php.ini and rebooted Apache.

Answer (score -1):

I got same problem in Live Server only. But its working on Local Machine. Adds BOM at the start of a file also its not working on Server. But working in local Machine. Some changes need in your Live code.

**1. Place the ob_start() in first line of your file.**

Example:

```
ob_start();    
$DOCROOTPATH = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];   
$DOCROOTBASEPATH = dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);    
include_once($DOCROOTPATH."/lib/commonarray.inc");    
include_once($DOCROOTPATH."/includes/class.payslip.php");    
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/menucontrol.php");    

define('FPDF_FONTPATH','fpdf/font/');    
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
```

**2. After the $pdf->Output(),you should place ob_end_flush() in Same File .**

Example:

```
$pdf=new PDF();     
$pdf->Open();     
$pdf->AliasNbPages();     
$pdf->AddPage();     
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);     
$pdf->pdfAllPages();      
$pdf->Output();      
ob_end_flush();
```

Now go to hit the browser and see the pdf which you want.

(OR)
Some editors adds **BOM** at the start of a file.

View your file in hex and remove it